# One more time A problem with multiplicative derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to experiment with higher order multiplicative derivative as :

```
Mder[f_, x_, 0] := f[x]
Mder[f_, x_, 1] := Limit[(f[x + h]/f[x])^(1/h), h -> 0]
Mder[f_, x_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := Nest[Mder[f, x, 1], x, n]
```

Mder[f_, x_, 1] works as expected for instance if $f[x\_]:= C a^x$, 
 Mder[f_, x_, 1] = a as expected. But when I try to evaluate  Mder[f, x, 2] MA returns

$\text{Limit}\left[\left(\frac{a[h+x]}{a[x]}\right)^{1/h}, h\rightarrow 0 \right]$

So I understand that Mder[f_, x_, 1] is a head. Nevertheless, is there a way to use Nest in this context.

Comment: I don't understand what answer you expect. `a` is a symbol, so `a[x]` and `a[h+x]` are just undefined functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to decide if you want to differentiate functions or expressions.  I choose to differentiate functions and offer the following

```
Mder1[f_, 0] := f
Mder1[f_, 1] := Module[{h}, 
     With[{result = Limit[(f[# + h]/f[#])^(1/h), h -> 0]},
     result &]]
Mder1[f_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := Nest[Mder1[#, 1] &, f, n]
```

This gives the following differentiation results - which I guess are correct.

```
Table[Mder1[a^# &, ii], {ii, 0, 3}]
(* {a^#1 &, a &, 1 &, 1 &} *)
```